# Estimate on Average of Function + its Integral by its Second derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $C^2$, show there exists a $C > 0$ s.t.

\begin{equation} \left | \frac{f(0)+f(1)}{2} - \int_0^1 f(x)  \right | \leq C \int_0^1 |f''(x)| \end{equation}

Attempt: We have by integration by parts

\begin{equation} \int_0^1 f(x) dx = f(1)-\int_0^1 xf'(x)  dx = f(1) - \frac{f'(1)}{2} -\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{2}f''(x)  dx   \end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{equation} f(1)-\frac{f'(1)}{2}-\int_0^1 f(x)dx = -\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{2}f''(x)  \end{equation} In particular,
\begin{equation} |f(1)-\frac{f'(1)}{2}-\int_0^1 f(x)dx| \leq \int_0^1|f''(x)|  \end{equation}
However, I am unsure how to get the desired inequality from this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you get the first " $=$" in your work ? and where is the $f(0)$.

Comment: I did integration by parts with $f(x)$ and 1 i.e. $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \int_0^1 1 \cdot f(x) = fx|_0^1 - \int_0^1 f'x dx$

Comment: @Story123 Unless you have assumed $f(0)=0$, there should also be a $-f(0)$ term in the equation that DeepSea has referenced.

Comment: Unless I am wrong, the boundary term should be $f(x)*x$ evaluated at $x=1$ and $x=0$ so it becomes $f(1)*1 - f(0)*0 = f(1)$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that replacing $f$ with 
$$
f + \text{a linear part (i.e. $ax+b$)}
$$

does not change either side of the inequality intended! Just check! Thus, you may assume that WLG that $f(1)=f'(1)=0$. Now your last line follows. (Just by crude estimate of $|x^2| \leq 1$ on the interval.

Comment: There is another solution based on similar simplification. Notice that both sides are also invariant under scalar multiplication of $f$. Thus, we may assume WLG that $f(0)+f(1)=0$, simply by subtracting a constant $c$ from $f$. Then by also scaling you may assume $\max |f''(x)| =1$. (Unless the trivial case of this quantity being zero.)

By intermediate value theorem there is an $c \in [0,1]$ with $f(c)=0$. Under the assumption $|f''|\leq 1$ there is a certain bound on the area $f$ can have between $0$ and $c$. Similarly, between $c$ and $1$. Analyze these bounds and maximize them.

Answer (score 2):

Define the following function : $$ F : x\mapsto\int_{0}^{x}{f\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}-f\left(1\right)x $$

$ \bullet \ F \in \mathscr{C}^{2}\left(\left[0,1\right],\mathbb{R}\right) \cdot $

Let's apply [Lagrange's generalised mean-value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) to $ f $ on a segment $ \left[0,1\right] $ : $$ F\left(1\right)-F\left(0\right)-\frac{F'\left(0\right)}{2}=\frac{F''\left(c\right)}{6},\ \ \ \text{For some }c\in\left[0,1\right] $$

$$ \iff \int_{0}^{1}{f\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}-\frac{f\left(0\right)+f\left(1\right)}{2}=\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{c}{f''\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{1}{6}f'\left(0\right) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

Thus : \begin{aligned} \left|\frac{f\left(0\right)+f\left(1\right)}{2}-\int_{0}^{1}{f\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}\right|&=\frac{1}{6}\left|\int_{0}^{c}{f''\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}\right|+\frac{1}{6}\left|f'\left(0\right)\right| \end{aligned}
Since $ \mathbb{R} $ has the Archimedean property, there is some $ n\in\mathbb{N} $, such that : $$ \left|f'\left(0\right)\right|\leq n\left|f'\left(1\right)-f'\left(0\right)\right|=n\left|\int_{0}^{1}{f''\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}\right|\leq n\int_{0}^{1}{\left|f''\left(t\right)\right|\mathrm{d}t} $$

Hence : \begin{aligned} \left|\frac{f\left(0\right)+f\left(1\right)}{2}-\int_{0}^{1}{f\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}\right|&\leq\frac{1}{6}\left|\int_{0}^{c}{f''\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}\right|+\frac{n}{6}\int_{0}^{1}{\left|f''\left(t\right)\right|\mathrm{d}t}\\ &\leq\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{c}{\left|f''\left(t\right)\right|\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{n}{6}\int_{0}^{1}{\left|f''\left(t\right)\right|\mathrm{d}t}\\ &\leq\frac{n+1}{6}\int_{0}^{1}{\left|f''\left(t\right)\right|\mathrm{d}t} \end{aligned}
In this case, our $ C $ would be $ \frac{n+1}{6} \cdot $

Comment: Is the $n$ independent of $f$?

Comment: Yes. You wanna prove that for each $ \mathcal{C}^{2} $ function $ f $, there exists some constant $ C $ that verifies the inequality. So you've got the result.